# Scope of variable defined in for loop header

Tags: kotlin

I noticed that the following Kotlin code compiles and executes successfully:

```
for (i in 1..2) {
    val i = "a"
    print(i)
}
```

This prints `aa`. However, I failed to find rationale behind the decision to allow this kind of variable shadowing. I would say that this is not a good practice, and is prohibited even in Java.

I think that Kotlin designers did a great work of improving Java syntax and accommodating it to the everyday practical use, so I must be missing something here?

Comment: This seems more like a statement/opinion than a question better for Kotlin discussion forums or Slack than for Stackoverflow.  Kotlin is consistent, as it is in this case with all other places you can shadow a variable, and receive IDE inspection warnings.  Change your warning level in the IDE for this inspection to an error.

Comment: @JaysonMinard Thanks. Are you aware of any links to the official documentation where the shadowing rules are explained?

Comment: I don't have a link offhand.  I just remember early discussions on the topic.  Really, I'd prefer you never could shadow a variable name anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kotlin does not restrict variable shadowing in any way.  The rationale is simple:  "*consistency*."

Since you could shadow variables in most other places why would you exclude only some loop variables from the allowed options?  Why would they be so special?  It is an arbitrary difference.

Any scope can shadow a variable used in another scope.  It is **NOT** good practice and does produce a compiler warning -- but it is allowed.

If you want to engage in a dialog with the contributors of the project, try the discussion forum or slack channel, both are linked from the [Kotlin Community page](https://kotlinlang.org/community.html).  Otherwise if you feel it is a bug please add an Issue report to [Kotlin YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2F) and the answer you receive there will be definitive as well.

In the meantime, you are free to write nonsensical code such as:

```kotlin
val i = 1
class Foo() {
    val i = "monkey"
    init { println(i) }
    @Test fun boo() {
        println(i)
        val i = i.length
        println(i)
        if (i == 6) {
            val i = Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + i) // Shadow warning
            println(i)
        }
        for (i in 0..i) {                                // Shadow warning
            val i = "chimp $i"                           // Shadow warning
            println(i)
        }
        InnerFoo()
    }
    class InnerFoo() {
        val i: Long = 100L
        init { println(i) }
    }
}
```

Which in Kotlin 1.0.3 produces 3 warnings.

> Warning:(15, 21) Kotlin: Name shadowed: i
> Warning:(18, 18) Kotlin: Name shadowed: i
> Warning:(19, 21) Kotlin: Name shadowed: i

And outputs:

> monkey
> monkey
> 6
> Sun Jul 17 11:31:23 UYT 2016
> chimp 0
> chimp 1
> chimp 2
> chimp 3
> chimp 4
> chimp 5
> chimp 6
> 100

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I wasn't aware that everything else can be shadowed as well, hence the loop example in my question.

Comment: Name shadowing is very useful when you have a constructor argument and a property with the same name, for example ;)